# Check if a servlet filter is registered

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters

In JSF, is there anyway to check whether a filter is registered for an application? I have some functionality that requires a filter exists, and I'd like to produce better error messages to explain that the filter does not exist and the functionality will be disabled. Basically, given a theoretical filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.SomeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'd like some way of checking `.isRegistered("com.example.SomeFilter")`.

I'd considered printing out the stack-trace and checking if the filter class exists there, but that seems like a hacky solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the `FilterRegistration` from the `ServletContext`.

```
ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
         .getExternalContext().getContext();

if(ctx.getFilterRegistration("SomeFilter") != null){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (except I went via an `HttpServletRequest`, `httpServletRequest.getServletContext().getFilterRegistrations()`